# Hexagon (Sudoku-like puzzle)

Tags: sudoku

This is the hexagon with digits to each row and diagonal which follow the rule :

- If the row and diagonal contains 5 triangles, it must contains all of the digits from 1 to 5.
- If the row and diagonal contains 7 triangles, it must contains all of the digits from 1 to 7.

[image]

There are many arrangement to create such hexagon.

**The Puzzle**

Replace each letter with numbers, which obey the rules.
I have put some numbers to some letter there, to make the puzzle unique.

[image]

Note : I think my wording is still a bit confusing, please edit it, for better puzzle.

Comment: What's the point in putting the letters in (except, perhaps, to give us a way to refer to the cells)? You're essentially giving us a blank grid with six numbers filled in, much like Sudokus — but Sudokus don't fill in all the empty cells with useless symbols. (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: @PeregrineRook To help others who can not edit picture answer the question. They can answer like A=1,B=2,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with

> placing the 6 and 7 in the middle in the only possible positions, it gets quite easy: the 4 on the very left can be placed, and it is straightforward from that point.
>  [image]